# Inserting script dynamically before another makes function return undefined

Tags: javascript

When I load a script using JavaScript it returns that the function set inside the script file is undefined.

This is my JavaScript inside `MC.js`:

```
    window._____$_scriptTag = null;
    function setScript(){
        var scripts = document.scripts || document.getElementsByTagName("script");
        window._____$_scriptTag = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
    }
    setScript();
MC.install = function(url){
        if(typeof url === "string"){
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = url;
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            window._____$_scriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, window._____$_scriptTag);
        } else if(typeof url === "object"){
            for(i = 0; i < url.length; i++){
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.src = url[i];
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                    window._____$_scriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, window._____$_scriptTag);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<script src='MoonCheeseJS.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<span>
    <br id='go'>
    <a class='my_a'></a>
</span>
<div id='div1' style='height: 250px; width: 100%;'></div>
<script>
    MC.install(["qwery.js", "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qwery/3.4.2/qwery.js", "sizzle.js"]);
    Sizzle("head");
</script>
```

I am using Google Chrome 32

The exact error it gives me in the Chrome console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Sizzle is not defined (index):12

Comment: Have you checked that the JS files are actually loaded?

Comment: I don't believe the loading of the script files is synchronous. You need to listen for the `load` events, and execute a callback when all scripts have loaded. That means you can't immediately call `Sizzle("head")` after the `MC.install()` line, and would instead have to do it in a callback you pass to `MC.install`

Comment: Do you realize that there is no point to dynamically adding a script tag in a specific spot relative to another one.  All dynamically added script tags are loaded asychronously (e.g. no defined load order).  If you a dynamically loaded script to execute AFTER another dynamically loaded script, then you have to register a load notification for the first script so you can execute the second script ONLY after the first one has successfully loaded.

Comment: Have you checked console for errors? What is `_____$_scriptTag`? Is it a valid reference?

Comment: also in this case you aren't doing anything with the return value, so if that is causing you confusion just delete the return statement

Comment: @MarcellFülöp The window._____$_scriptTag is set.

Comment: @lan Can you please explain that.

Comment: @Nick actuallly it's part of a library that I'm creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel? Use something like [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: But I am creating my own library.